# Project is not launched when clicked from PhpMyadmin list of projects

Tags: wamp, phpmyadmin

PhpMyadmin list of projects shows the project I want to launch :

[image]

After clicking the project **finapro2** then the browser shows "we can not find this site." ; and the address bar is `http://finapro2`

I use **WampServer 2.5**

So how to make the project launched from PhpMyadmin ?

Comment: That is the WAMPServer Homepage and not phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really create a [Virtual Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) for each of your projects.

However you could also tell WAMPServer to add `localhost` to the url like this

```
[Right click]wampmanager icon->Wamp Settings-> Add localhost in url
```

> But the better solution is to create a Virtual Host for each new project as per the link above